# Is there a way to sum a bunch of IMPORTDATA() outputs?

Tags: google-sheets

I am attempting to sum quite a few different ranges of `IMPORTDATA()`

I want to do something like:

```
=SUM(N9:N14,N16:N21,N23:N36,N38:N53,N55:N106,N108:N113)
```

My issue is it can't sum up a bunch of different `IMPORTDATA()`. 
It is reading what is inside and not what is being shown.

Answer (score 0):

For what I tried so far it doesn't. Doesn't work like excel in that aspect. Either you can paste the range using Importrange("url","sheet!A:A") which will populate the column with all A:A data from external sheet or copy and paste the data values and then work with it.

Comment: Actually, you could (unless they are many) sum(importdata(1), importdata(2)...importdata(n)), that should work as each importdata returns a value and sum() can add those values